# How to stream swf in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, flash

I am planning to create a Windows Phone 7.1 (Mango) Application. I wanted to see if i can stream swf directly from the web to the app?

Regards,
Bhavik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Phone 7 does not yet support flash (although I remember when it was rumored to be launched with it) so I highly doubt this is possible.